# np.random.choice() doesn't accept a list of probabilites

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to use [np.random.choice()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) to get a random value from a list based on given probabilities. 
I noticed, however, that when I try to pass a list of probabilities directly to the function I get the error message `TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`; Instead, when I write the list explictly in the function call, everything works as it should.

See the example below to understand what I mean:

```
>>> p = [0.5, 0.5]
>>> np.random.choice(["h","t"],p)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1163, in mtrand.RandomState.choice
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 995, in mtrand.RandomState.randint
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 996, in mtrand.RandomState.randint
  File "randint_helpers.pxi", line 202, in mtrand._rand_int32
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
>>> np.random.choice(["h","t"],p=[0.5,0.5])
't'
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to fix the error and be able to pass a list to the function? I obviously cannot hardcode the probabilities inside my program and can't understand how or why numpy is complaining.

EDIT: Noticed that I should pass p=p to the function right after posting this, I'm leaving it up as an example of why you should always rubber duck all your bugs

Comment: Pass `p=p` explicitly. The second argument is probably the size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of the function is `np.random.choice(a, size=None, replace=None, p=None)`. So if you don't specify which variable to pass to, then `np.random.choice(["h","t"],p)` will interpret `p` as `size`, which is an `int` or a tuple of `int`. To fix it, do `np.random.choice(["h","t"],p=p)`.

Comment: I noticed this right after writing the question and came back to take it down, but since you already answered I'm going to leave it up as a testament to why you should be rubberducking the shit out of your bugs :)